# Cassandra. How to create column family using FluentCassandra API?

Tags: c#, cassandra, column-family

I'm trying to create column family with this code

```
 

    public void CreateAColumnFamily()
     {
      using (var db = new CassandraContext(keyspace:"Earth", 
        server: Server))
      {
        CassandraColumnFamily cf = db.GetColumnFamily("People");
        if (cf == null)
        {
          db.ExecuteNonQuery(@"CREATE COLUMNFAMILY People (
            KEY ascii PRIMARY KEY,
            FirstName text,
            LastName text,
            Age int,
            Title text
    );");
        }
        cf = db.GetColumnFamily("People");
      }
    }
```

But nothing to happening. If i just to execute command **create column family People** in cassandra-cli - column family is creating. What i do wrong?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: @Raedwald FluentCassandra == C#

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that they column family 'People' already exists, and it shouldn't if you are trying to create it.

> db.GetColumnFamily("People"); // means we are getting an existing CF

To create a column family:

```
db.TryCreateColumnFamily(new CassandraColumnFamilySchema
{
    FamilyName = "Tags",
    KeyValueType = CassandraType.AsciiType,
    ColumnNameType = CassandraType.Int32Type,
    DefaultColumnValueType = CassandraType.UTF8Type
});
```

Source: [Example from fluent cassandra github](https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/test/FluentCassandra.Sandbox/Program.cs#L45).

Also as a *side note*. I struggled with finding documentation for fluent cassandra and it looks like you did too. If you are learning Cassandra try out the [datastax C# driver](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver)... lots of documentation and a bigger community behind it.